# Traffic lights on vue.js doesn't work, how to solve?

Tags: html, css, vue.js

I created a traffic light using vue.js, but it doesn't work. It should display the colours (red, yellow and green) according to the time duration. Is there a problem that I've missed?

CSS

```
#screen {
width: 450px;
height: 740px;
background: #222; 
border-radius: 12px;
margin: auto;
padding: 23px;
}

.light {
    width: 230px;
    height: 270px;
    display: inline-block;
    opacity: 0.2;
    border-radius: 100%;
    transition: opacity 10s;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
}

.active {
    opacity: 1;
}
.red {
    background: red;
}

.yellow {
    background: yellow;
}

.green {
    background: green;
}
```

My HTMl
I've created the divs.

```
<div id="screen">
<div id="light red"  :class="{active: now=='red'}"></div>
<div id="light yellow"  :class="{active: now=='yellow'}"></div>
<div id="light green"  :class="{active: now=='green'}"></div>
</div>
```

and this is vue.js
It seems like everything on it's place and console doesn't send any error.
But I still can't understand, why it isn't working?

```
class State {
  constructor(name, dur, next){
    this.name = name;
    this.dur = dur;
    this.next = next;
  }
}

class Constroller {
  trigger(state, callback){
    callback(state);
    setTimeout(()=>{
      this.trigger(state.next, callback);
    }, state.dur * 10)
  }
}


var app = new Vue({
el: '#screen', 
  data:{
    now: 'red'
  },
  mounted(){
    var constroller = new Constroller();

    var red = new State('red', 2);
    var yellowRed = new State('yellow', 1);
    var yellowGreen = new State('yellow', 1);
    var green = new State('green', 3);

    red.next = yellowRed;
    yellowR.next = green;
    green.next = yellowGreen;
    yellowG.next = red;

    constroller.trigger(red, (state)=>{
      this.now = state.name;
    });

  }
})
```

Am I missing smth? Should I rewrite my function?

Answer (score 3):

Well there are several things wrong here:

```
<div id="light red"  :class="{active: now=='red'}"></div>
<div id="light yellow"  :class="{active: now=='yellow'}"></div>
<div id="light green"  :class="{active: now=='green'}"></div>
```

Should be class instead of id.

```
var red = new State('red', 2);
var yellowRed = new State('yellow', 1);
var yellowGreen = new State('yellow', 1);
var green = new State('green', 3);

red.next = yellowRed;
yellowR.next = green;
green.next = yellowGreen;
yellowG.next = red;
```

You named `yellowRed` and `yellowGreen` but then used `yellowR` and `YellowG`

Anyway, I made a quick fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/Lo50j4rw/ that you can check out, I also tweak some duration stuff.
Also, at least in my country the light goes green after red :D

Comment: Thank's a lot! Sure, I changed  the name of the variables. And add class instead of id.

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem is that you used `id` where you should have used `class` for your HTML light elements. You also had weird choices for timing: each light had a very short duration, but the transition was 10 seconds.

Fixing those, you get this:

```js
class State {
  constructor(name, dur, next) {
    this.name = name;
    this.dur = dur;
    this.next = next;
  }
}

class Constroller {
  trigger(state, callback) {
    callback(state);
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.trigger(state.next, callback);
    }, state.dur * 1000)
  }
}

new Vue({
  el: '#screen',
  data: {
    now: 'red'
  },
  mounted() {
    var constroller = new Constroller();

    var red = new State('red', 2);
    var yellowRed = new State('yellow', 1);
    var yellowGreen = new State('yellow', 1);
    var green = new State('green', 3);

    red.next = yellowRed;
    yellowRed.next = green;
    green.next = yellowGreen;
    yellowGreen.next = red;

    constroller.trigger(red, (state) => {
      this.now = state.name;
    });

  }
})
```

```css
#screen {
width: 450px;
height: 740px;
background: #222; 
border-radius: 12px;
margin: auto;
padding: 23px;
}

.light {
    width: 230px;
    height: 270px;
    display: inline-block;
    opacity: 0.2;
    border-radius: 100%;
    transition: opacity 0.3s;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
    background-color: white;
}

.active {
    opacity: 1;
}
.red {
    background: red;
}

.yellow {
    background: yellow;
}

.green {
    background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="screen">
  <div class="light red" :class="{active: now=='red'}"></div>
  <div class="light yellow" :class="{active: now=='yellow'}"></div>
  <div class="light green" :class="{active: now=='green'}"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! yeah, I change the duration, it was just a sample. Thank you. sometimes I miss the important things in my code.